# How to call token in config.headers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, api, axios

You will see console.logs in the if loop for uberToken and adminToken. When I run any of my api tests, the admin and uber token is printed on the console no problem. But I can't call it outside in the **config.headers['Authorization']** part.How to call uberToken and adminToken in config.headers?

Taking below error;

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0**

```
   at core/axios.ts:20

  18 |       const uberJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${configAuth.UberAuth}`))
  19 |       uberJson.origins[0].localStorage.forEach((item) => {
> 20 |         if (Object.keys((JSON.parse(item.value))).includes("token")) {
     |                               ^
  21 |           uberToken = (JSON.parse(item.value)).token
  22 |           console.log('uberToken', uberToken)
  23 |         }
```

the code;

```
import axios from "axios";
import { configAuth, configEnv } from "../config/config"
var fs = require('fs')

let uberToken = null
let adminToken = null
const customAxios = axios.create({
  baseURL: configEnv.apiBaseURL,
});

axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async (config) => {
    if (config.headers) {

      const { admin } = config.params || {};
      const uberJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${configAuth.UberAuth}`))
      uberJson.origins[0].localStorage.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (Object.keys((JSON.parse(item.value))).includes("token")) {
          uberToken = (JSON.parse(item.value)).token
          console.log('uberToken', uberToken)
        }
      })
      const adminJson = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(`./${configAuth.AdminAuth}`))
      adminJson.origins[0].localStorage.forEach((item: any) => {
        if (Object.keys((JSON.parse(item.value))).includes("token")) {
          adminToken = (JSON.parse(item.value)).token
          console.log('adminToken', adminToken)
        }
      })
      config.headers['Authorization'] = admin ? `Bearer ${adminToken}` : `Bearer ${uberToken}`;
      return config;
    }
    return config;
  }
)
```